# Using Embedded picture in mutliple c files

Tags: c

I have an emebedded project that contains several images to be displayed on the screen. The images are stored in binary color in header files.
I want to use the image in two different places in the project. But including the header file in both c files causes the linking to fail since it wants to link the image twice.

how do i organize it to be linked only once?

Comment: Declare the variable `static` so it's private to each source file.

Comment: Better not put data in header files. Put the data in a C module, and reference it from a header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the header file should not contain any code or data.

In the header file just have the external declarations.

Image.h

```
  extern char image[];
```

Image.c

```
  char image[] = {/* image data */};
```

Comment: how do I get the size of the array if i put the extern declaration in the header file

        sizeof(image) 

does not work.

Comment: you can declare it explicit or use struct instead. BTW you know the size of the image so you can calculate the size of the array.

Answer (score -4):

Technically, your header file should get included only once in your project. To ensure that, most people use a include guard. Are you using an include guard?

Wikipedia has a nice page explaining [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

TLDR; 
Use

```
#ifndef IMAGE_H
#define IMAGE_H

// Original header file data
// Like the binary color information,etc.

#endif /* IMAGE_H */
```

Comment: This only has an effect when the same header file is included multiple times within a single C file.  It has no effect when the header is included by separate C files. The same data will end up in separate object files, that is what the linker is complaining about..